# How do I eliminate white noise in zynaddsubfx?

Tags: sound, midi

How do you eliminate white noise in zynaddsubfx? I am using the synthesizer with a midi program and qjackctl. It works, but there is some noise in the background. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I managed to decrease the white noise a lot. It was a latency issue again. This is what I did. In Zynaddsubfx, I went to Edit, then I enabled Padsynth and clicked Edit. Then I saw that the sample size was 128 and not 256. I changed this, and then clicked on apply.

Answer (score 0):

Along with the above answer, I also discovered that if if you disable the sustain setting a lot of the white noise will be eliminated. This is what I did. After clicking on Edit Instrumment in zynaddsubfx, you come to a window where you will see this:

[image: white noise 1.png]

Click on the E. Then you will come to a window like this:

[image: white noise 2.png]

Make sure that FreeMode is selected and put Sust at 0. Then close the window. This will eliminate alot of noise that you may not want.